# How can i get the current Fragment ID

Tags: android, fragment

I did a navigation drawer, and I’ve set some items and normally when I select an item the current fragment will be changed by a new one, it's not the case for me, the first Activity still displayed even if the fragments change. This is my `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected`method and it's clear I change the fragment every time i click on a new one.

```
 @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    // TODO : Added
    switch(position) {
        /*case 0 :
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new ProfilFrgement())
                    .commit();
            break;*/
        case 1:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new SpotFragement())
                    .commit();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new SessionsFragement())
                    .commit();
            break;
        /*case 3:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new EventsFragment())
                    .commit();
            break;*/

    }

}
```

I think my problem is a change always the same container. So what I need its getting the current fragment ID

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for too late but I have a solution to get fragment ID. You can use name of Fragment Class as an Identifier not the ID. Use a static String variable to store class name.

```
public class Activity{
...
static String currentFragment = null;
...
...
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_one:
            setFragment(new oneFragment());
            break;
        case R.id.nav_two:
            setFragment(new twoFragment());
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void setFragment(@NonNull Fragment f) {
    if(!f.getClass().getName().equals(currentFragment)){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, f);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    currentFragment = f.getClass().getName();
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What is current fragment ID here? Ur id is R.id.container which is only one rt? then what is the question about "How can i get the current Fragment ID"?

If question is to find which is the current fragment is shown to user? If yes then

```
Fragment ft = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);

if (ft instanceof SpotFragement) {
// navigation drawer item 1 and current fragment is SpotFragment.
} else if (ft instanceof SessionsFragement) {

}
```

Comment: I have an activity that host the navigation drawer, and after the item click I change the fragment but the contain of the container don't display off.

Comment: ur fragment is not displayed in the container?

Comment: Yes. But the container contains a message that I have to test if the changes pass very well, and this is not the case (i don't know if the should be blank)

Comment: If possible, you can share the code or some link to download the project.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your container styling is correct.
Check following values of container once -

- android:layout_width
- android:layout_height

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"` Why ?